# Texlipse and git - two repositories

Tags: texlipse, git

I'd like to use texlipse and git. I managed to create a project (`/data/workspace/proj`) and and a repository (`/data/git/proj`). Texlipse or git moved all files from `workspace/git` to `git/proj` which seems to be my "workspace" now.
Why are there no files in `/workspace` anymore?
I'd like to clone the `/git/proj` repository to `/workspace/proj`, in order to have the project in `/workspace` again and to have a „clean“ repository in `/git/proj` and the productive repository in `/workspace/proj`.
This would be helpful because I'd like to move `/data/git` to an external storage to have a backup.
How do I achieve this?